# Style a particular div despite it's position among many div within a div using only CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to select the the first div with con and car among all the div using css selector.

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="con">1</div>
  <div class="con be">2</div>
  <div class="con car">3</div>
  <div class="con">4</div>
  <div class="con be">5</div>
  <div class="con car">6</div>
</div>
```

And the con and car div can be in any place. Since it's the 3rd child right now I can call it by putting nth child as 3rd child. But it is the first div with con and car class. I may add more con and car class div's but I want to be able to select and style the first con and car div despite it's position. How can I do that??

Comment: Not possible. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/151509 and see if you can find workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to target the classes you DON'T want to style using the [subsequent-sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators) `~`

```css
.con.car ~ .con.car {
  background: none;
}

.con.car {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="con">1</div>
  <div class="con be">2</div>
  <div class="con car">3</div>
  <div class="con">4</div>
  <div class="con be">5</div>
  <div class="con car">6</div>
</div>
```

However, this is done much more simply using JavaScript

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("con car")[0].style.background = "red";
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="con">1</div>
  <div class="con be">2</div>
  <div class="con car">3</div>
  <div class="con">4</div>
  <div class="con be">5</div>
  <div class="con car">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I select the 2nd or 3rd class or any particular one I want with con and car despite it's position?? If JavaScript is needed then you can also tell me that.

Comment: See updated answer.